# how to write equivalent java code to "git diff tag1 tag2 --some/file/path"

Tags: java, jgit

I try to implement the function like following:

```java
public List<RevCommit> createFileHistoryFromTag(File file, String fromTag,
        String toTag) {
    Iterable<RevCommit> commits = null;
    try {
        List<Ref> refs = git.tagList().call();
        ObjectId fromTagId = null;
        ObjectId toTagId = null;
        for (Ref refTag : refs) {
            if (refTag.getName().equals(fromTag)) {
                fromTagId = refTag.getObjectId();
            } else if (refTag.getName().equals(toTag)) {
                toTagId = refTag.getObjectId();
            }
        }
        if (fromTagId == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't resolve fromTag: "
                    + fromTag + " Make sure you gave an existing ref");
        }
        if (toTagId == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't resolve toCommit: "
                    + toTag + " Make sure you gave an existing ref");
        }
        commits = getCommitListFromTagForFile(file.getAbsolutePath()
                .substring(1), fromTagId, toTagId);

    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Lists.newArrayList(commits);
}
```

and the geCommitListFromTagForFile like following:

```java
private RevCommitList<RevCommit> getCommitListFromTagForFile(String path,
        ObjectId start, ObjectId end) throws IOException {
    RevWalk revisionWalk = buildRevisionWalk(path, start, end);
    final RevCommitList<RevCommit> list = new RevCommitList<>();
    list.source(revisionWalk);
    list.fillTo(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return list;
}
```

finally buildRevisionWalk function

```java
private RevWalk buildRevisionWalk(String path, ObjectId start, ObjectId end)
        throws IOException {

    Config config = new Config(git.getRepository().getConfig());
    config.setString("diff", null, "renames", "copies");
    config.setInt("diff", null, "renameLimit", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    DiffConfig diffConfig = config.get(DiffConfig.KEY);

    final RevWalk revisionWalk = new RevWalk(git.getRepository());
    revisionWalk.setTreeFilter(FollowFilter.create(path, diffConfig));
    revisionWalk.markStart(revisionWalk.parseCommit(start));

    if (end != null) {
        revisionWalk.markUninteresting(revisionWalk.parseCommit(end));
    }
    return revisionWalk;
}
```

But it won't return any commit message, if one file between two tags is changed.
Basically I want the functionality like 
git diff v.4.32b759 v4.32b760 --some/file/path
and get the commit message from this tag